# Classifier does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here

Tags: android, kotlin, interface

I have an Activity where an interface is declared and I have a `ViewModel` class which has overridden interface and want to invoke the method of interface from `Activity` to make changes in `ViewModel` class but unable to call method in `Activity` saying **ViewModel class does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here**. How to resolve this?

```
var selection: setSelectionSubRow? = null
    selection=RowSubTShirtViewModel
    selection!!.setNameSelection(false)
```

above code is in `Activity` whose name is `TShirtActivity`.

below code is from `RowViewModel` class

```
class RowSubTShirtViewModel(private val subTShirtAdapter: SubTShirtAdapter, val context: TShirtActivity,
                        val tShirtBean: CommonItemBean, private val parentPosition: Int, private val position: Int) : BaseObservable() ,TShirtActivity.setSelectionSubRow{

fun getImageDrawable(): Drawable {
    return if (tShirtBean.isSelected)
        ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.green_border_circle)!!
    else
        ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.border_circle)!!
}

override fun setNameSelection(selection: Boolean) {
    if (parentPosition == 6) {
        if (position == 1) {
            tShirtBean.isSelected = false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

This line `selection=RowSubTShirtViewModel` references the view model as if it were a named object, meaning you would have written instead of class object:

```
object RowSubTShirtViewModel {
   //...
}
```

However, since that's not the case, kotlin is telling you that you cannot reference it like that and must initialize it. The constructor as quite a lot of parameters for me to guess what they are, but essentially you'd have to pass them in:

```
selection=RowSubTShirtViewModel(/*parameters here*/)
```

Comment: I got your point. but other problems have to face, Actually this `RowSubTShirtViewModel ` is a `viewmodel` of `subAdapter` class and it is using in  `ViewModel`  class of  `Activity` and there is a `dialog` in `activity`, in `dialog` on button click I want to reverse selection of `RecycleView` item and the `RowSubTShirtViewModel` is a `viewModel` for the adpater of that `recyclerview`, so how can i manage constructor of  `RowSubTShirtViewModel` in `Acitivty`

Comment: That's just a classic dependency problem. You just carry on passing everything until you have all you need. For example, if you construct `RowSubTShirtViewModel` in the adapter, which is used in an activity, then you can pass the activity as you instantiate the adapter and then pass it in as you instantiate `RowSubTShirtViewModel`. There are other approaches using dependency injection frameworks like Dagger. I can't really tell you what suits you best, but the problem you're having will always lead to having to build `RowSubTShirtViewModel`.

Comment: Thanks Fred I will look both the solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Having a companion object (and having members *in* that companion object) in Kotlin is equivalent to having static members (static methods or fields) in Java, and as it is known, static members in Java can be accessed without initializing the class or having a reference to an object of that class. For example, given:

```java
// this is Java
class A {
  static void s() {System.out.println("static");}
  void d() {System.out.println("dynamic");}
}
```

we could call the `s()` method without initializing the class `A`, like this: `A.s();`, and it would print "static", but in order to be able to call the `d()` method, we need an *object* of the `A` class, which we can get by either initializing it elsewhere like this: `A a = A();`, and then doing `a.d();` or doing them together like this: `A().d();`, both of which would print "dynamic".

Even though Kotlin does not have the `static` keyword, it must have the same functionality since any Java code can be translated into Kotlin code. Now when we want to transfer this train of thought into Kotlin, we would instead say something like "in order to use members from the companion object (static members, basically), you must initialize the class name (i.e. create an object)".

So when Kotlin complains and says **Classifier `Something` does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here**, it is basically telling you that that class does not have any static members (since it does not have a companion object), and so if you want to use it, either use it with parenthesis (initialize it to create an object of it), or declare a companion object in it (using the `companion object` keyword).

I hope this clears things up. Sadly, uninformative messages like this prove that you need prior Java understanding to learn Kotlin, a fact that haunts it and will hinder its ability to stand alone as a language.

Comment: Yes, I keep discovering that last point the hard way. I know some C++ but no Java. Google sings the praises of Kotlin but doesn't go far enough to support it, and I see more Java code than Kotlin. If I had done more research, I might have discovered that Java was better supported than Kotlin, making me think it was a mistake to learn Kotlin instead of Java.

Answer (score 4):

For those who didn't find the correct answer, the issue is because the inline function syntax was wrong.

The correct syntax is:

```
val selection: RowSubTShirtViewModel by viewModels()
```

Assigning a class to variable requires the class to be an object.

Answer (score 1):

in my case, I got this error in `ApplicationModule` for `dagger2`.

```
@Provides
@Singleton

 internal fun providesxx(xx: xxx): xx {
        return xx
    }
```

I just Rename the argument!